# .htaccess redirect all subfolders to root domain if GET parameter is empty

Tags: .htaccess

need help with htaccess rules.
I need to redirect all requests to folders/subfolders to root domain when GET parameter is empty.

eg:

```
http://example.com/folder1/ -> http://example.com/
http://example.com/folder2/ -> http://example.com/
http://example.com/folder2/subdir3/ -> http://example.com/
```

If in url GET params indicated and subfolder3 exist then no redirects.

```
http://example.com/folder3/?a=11&b=22 - no redirect
http://example.com/folder2/?b=22 - no redirect
http://example.com/ - no redirects
```

I have made like this, but after redirecting to root it has too many redirects.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Wrong close vote here. As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why you are getting redirect loop because you are not checking for request being a directory and using `.*` in the `RewriteRule` pattern that also matches landing page.

You may use this rule to handle these redirects from any folder to root:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
```

**Details:**

- `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`: Check to make sure query string is empty
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`: Check to make sure that request is for a directory
- `RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]`: to make sure that we are not on the landing page already by matching a dot regex pattern. `/` in target redirects all the matching requests to root page with http code `301`.

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely or test in a new browser.

Comment: Thank you anubhava for your answere. It works. 
What condition should I use if there is a a excaption folder. for example subfolder /blog/

Comment: For that add a new negative condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/` before `RewriteRule` line.